# gallery and music player are not working

Tags: gallery

My gallery is not showing pics and videos of SD card
So I installed quickpic which is showing every thing
My music player is also not showing my music
I have restarted the phone my times after this but it won't help
Pls help

Answer (score 1):

1. go to *settings>Apps>all>Gallery*
2. a)click on force stop

   b)click on clear data

   c)click on clear cache
3. now again go to *settings>Apps>all>music*
4. a)click on force stop

   b)click on clear data

   c)click on clear cache
5. now again go to *settings>Apps>all>Media Storage*
6. a)click on force stop

   b)click on clear data

   c)click on clear cache

7.Now,restart phone

**note:-** wait for 2-3 minutes to allow gallery and music player to build their database again.